# If $f$ is one to one on $C$ then $f$ is one to one in $C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic inside and on the simple closed curve $C$ and is one to one on the trace of $C$. I need to prove that $f$ is one to one inside the interior of $C$ as well.

Since $C$ is simple and closed clearly $f(C)$ which is the image of $f$ on the trace $C$ is also a simple closed curve. From here on I feel like the argument principle can be used to solve the rest but I just cannot seem to do it. Any help is appreciated thanks